# Bluetooth not available: Mojave 10.14.2

Tags: macos, bluetooth, mojave

I have a MacBook Pro Retina (2015). After updating to OS Mojave, Bluetooth has stopped working. I get an error message that "No Bluetooth Hardware Found".

I have already tried to do the following:

1. Go to the /Library/Preferences and delete the `com.apple.Bluetooth.plist` file
2. Successfully resetting SMC. (pressing Shift+ctrl+alt + power button)
3. Removing the Bluetooth icon from the menu bar
4. [Successfully resetting NVRAM.](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204063)

**None of the above solutions has worked for me.**

Answer (score 2):

It may be necessary for the Bluetooth demon to be stopped when deleting the file. Here's what worked for me (some of this may be unnecessary or redundant):

1. Turn off bluetooth, e.g. from the toolbar icon.
2. Run this command (you'll probably be prompted for your password):

   ```
   sudo pkill bluetoothd \
       && sudo rm /Library/Preferences/com.apple.Bluetooth.plist \
       && sudo pkill bluetoothd
   ```
3. Go to the Bluetooth System Preferences pane and click the "Show bluetooth in menu bar" checkbox *twice* (to remove and then re-show it).
4. In the Bluetooth System Preferences pane, delete the device you want to connect to.
5. Turn on bluetooth.
6. Turn that device on and in pairing mode.
7. Pair with it.

It was not necessary for me to do anything with the SMC or NVRAM, or restart the machine.

Comment: You are basically deleting the `com.apple.Bluetooth.plist` which I already tried....didn't work :(

Comment: That and some other steps...I was not successful merely deleting it but was successful with the steps I mentioned. I can't say for sure that the extra steps were responsible for the success, but it might be worth a try for you.

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot open Bluetooth in System Preferences, it tells me "You can’t open the “Bluetooth” preferences pane because it is not available to you at this time."

Answer (score 2):

It's frequent on my MacBook Pro, but I don't have to do anything drastic.

I just follow these steps in order:

1. Go to **System Preferences** -> **Bluetooth**
2. Click on **Turn Bluetooth Off** button
3. Uncheck **Show Bluetooth in menu bar**
4. Check again **Show Bluetooth in menu bar**
5. Click on **Turn Bluetooth Off** button

Not sure if it's just luck but I don't need to do anything else.

Answer (score 1):

A colleague of mine had accidentally removed the list of all the connected wifi networks on my system which has since resolved this issue for me!

Comment: And how to do that?

Comment: @skm By going to Preferences -> Network-> Wi-Fi-> Advanced and selecting all networks and clicking - sign. BUT I think before this destructive action which also appears to be not connected to Bluetooth functionality, I suggest reboot or updates.

Comment: @ankiiiiiii: I already re-installed the whole OS but still did not work. I posted this question several months ago and since then I have tried several things but nothing worked.

Comment: I'm currently on 10.14.5 and had been having this issue since 10.14.2 on my MBP 2015. Bluetooth worked after a restart but then magically started showing Bluetooth not available.  I know it sounds weird but as I understand, the wireless card is common for both WiFi and Bluetooth. Also, after re-installing the OS, your iCloud restores the list of connected WiFi networks so that might be a reason why it's not worked for you till now(was the case with me). Let me know if it works for you! @skm

Comment: @RohanVir: did not work for me....I deleted all Wi-fi networks and even rebooted my MacBook but still, Bluetooth is not available :(

Answer (score 1):

I had the "bluetooth not available" and tried all the solutions. My problem ended up to be a loose cable that connects the motherboard to the wifi/bluetooth device mounted near the hinge. Once a repair guy pointed out the config, I just pushed down on on the bottom of the laptop case in the middle and it worked.

Comment: I have updated my OS to "Catalina" but still the problem is the same. I think I might also have some hardware issues. Could you please include some pictures in your answer to clarify which cable needs to fix properly.

Answer (score 0):

In terminal, also remove the com.apple.driver.AppleBluetoothMultitouch.trackpad.plist and com.apple.driver.AppleBluetoothMultitouch.mouse.plist files from ~/Library/Preferences.

```
cd ~/Library/Preferences
sudo rm com.apple.driver.AppleBluetoothMultitouch.mouse.plist
sudo rm com.apple.driver.AppleBluetoothMultitouch.trackpad.plist
```

Then restart.
That fixed it for me.

Answer (score 0):

Like one other person I read about, this same Bluetooth issue for me was caused by a new Displayport cable from my second monitor (I'm running two external monitors) to my Macbook Pro 2015 Mojave 10.14.6 (the other person said it was an HDMI cable from their second monitor).

Resetting PRAM worked once. As did deleting .plist files, but the issue would return after each restart.

I went back to the old VGA monitor cable and the issue was resolved.